# Can 3rd party apps access Siri on tvOS?

Tags: ios, tvos, siri

Is there an API to use Siri to search content within my app on tvOS? How about for searching for content within my app, while you're using Siri search from the home screen?

In either case, what's the API I should look at? I've read some things from a few months ago saying they would eventually open Siri for 3rd party app development, but I can't find any more info about that.

Comment: Well with my current experience SIRI is not open to developers yet and they are planning to open in near future idk when. I was also working for one of my application to integrate Search feature from iPhone and use SIRI as well but could not find any third party API for that. Let me know if you find any ! As far as search i have seen that HULU , NET FLIX application which are mainly build on TVML and TVJS frameworks offers search capability for the contents visible on the screen. Just a fyi if you want to use search feature my any chance you can try sending search data through mic to the tvOS